# Android - How to save an array on internal storage

Tags: android, arrays, persist

my question is about the following.

Im just trying to generate a new txt file in my internal storage. Inside it i will have just an array converted to string to save some IDs that i need to persist.

After that i need to read that file too but i don't know how to start.

I think is something like this:

```
   private void GsonWriter(ArrayList<Integer> arrayListTouched){

    String str = arrayListTouched.toString();
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're already using Gson.

How to save it.

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<>(); // Integer in your case. But can be any type

// save this string
String arrayString = gson.toJson(array);
```

How to load it.

```
ArrayList<Integer> array = gson.fromJson(arrayString, new TypeToken<ArrayList<Integer>>(){}.getType());
```

I assume you know how to save/load the string

Comment: I know that Gson is the way to do it. I dont know how to save this in a file and then read it too

Comment: @CiroGonzález use search for `how to save string in a file`